# Two parallel system problem

Tags: partitioning

So, an upgrade to 20 (from 18.04) crashed on me Saturday. I had no access to the net to ask questions but eventually found that I had an old version 16 installation disk. I used the disk just to get on the net to download 20.x. I installed in parallel to the old system so that I wouldn't lose my data.

That's okay except that I need to start at ground zero -- software installs, configurations, on and on.

1. How do I get my old configs back?
2. I can't simply copy my data to active partition. I run out of space. How can I do that?
3. And another specific issue. My text editor of choice since the 90's is joe. I downloaded it and worked with it yesterday, but I now get this error:

joe: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How do I fix that?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 is a very different system to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Are you sure you weren't upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  Ubuntu uses the *year* format for *snap* only releases, which are not the same products as the standard *year.month* format products; you need to re-install and not upgrade to switch from one to the other.  You can upgrade via re-install without starting again, esp. if you're talking about a *year.month* release and desktop - but your question is anything but clear with imprecise details.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libncurses5 to install the older version of ncurses, alternatively you could try to find a newer version of joe.

with regards to the old system, I would try to boot or chroot into it and run `apt-get -f install` to attempt to continue the upgrade process from where it failed.

Search for "chroot into linux partition" if you don't know how. But I'd be surprised if your old system weren't bootable from grub still?